# Плавный скрул к блоку по клику при разрешении меньше чем... jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

Мне нужно сделать плавный скрул к блоку на мобильных устройствах, но не знаю как реализовать проверку. Надеюсь на помощь. Делаю так, но не работает.

```js
  $(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(window) <= "600") {
      $('.ionTabs__head li').on('click', function() {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: $('.content-body').offset().top
        }, 200);
      });
    }
  });
```

Comment: То есть чтобы скрипт срабатывал если разрешение меньше 600, и отключался если разрешение превышало допустимую цифру.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что-то наподобие этого должно работать...

```
var ori = window.orientation,
    width = (ori===90 || ori===-90) ? screen.height : screen.width;

$(window).on('resize load', function () {

  ori = window.orientation,
  width = (ori===90 || ori===-90) ? screen.height : screen.width;

});


$('.ionTabs__head li').on('click', function() {

  if (width < 600){
    $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: $('.content-body').offset().top
    }, 200);
  }

});
```

Comment: Работает, ровно до ресайза. Если окно растянуть больше 600 пикселей по ширине, а потом сузить до значения меньше 600 - перестает работать.

Comment: @Александр
значит что то не так делаете, на чём тестируете, девайс?

Comment: замечу: работает именно на моб.устройствах и эмулях, на десктопе меняя границы - разумеется ориентация не пройдёт....

Comment: Да, спасибо. На мобильных работает.